# Pandas Dummy Variables with Count

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

Instead of using get_dummies(), the ask over here is to have count .
Eg: Consider T Shirt Sold at during each hour window.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':   [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],
                     'Sale': ['M','M','S','S','M','XL','S','M','M','S','S','M','XL','XL'],
               })
```

> Output

```
Time,   S,M,XL
0,  1,2,0
1,  1,1,1
```

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.Time,df.Sale)` ?

Comment: I like the answer above using `crosstab`. You can also use `groupby` after passing your data through the `get_dummies`. `pd.get_dummies(df).groupby('Time').agg(np.sum)`

Comment: Both Worked.. Please mark them as Answer..